# Passing error message from action method in a parent component back to the child component that called it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My router 6 setup in **App.js** is as follows:

```
const router=createBrowserRouter([{
    path:'/',
    element: <MainHeader/>, // wraps around all the child routes below
    errorElement:<Error/>, // displays this page upon an error
    id:'root',
    loader:tokenLoader,
    action:actionLogin,
    children:[
    .........................
```

**MainHeader.js**:

```
let token=useLoaderData()   
const actiondata = useActionData()

// This isn't executing when the action returns
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(actiondata)
},[actiondata])
    
return(
        <>
            {!token && <Login error={actiondata} />}
            ...........
        </>)
        
export async function action({request, params}){
    try{
        const result=await fetch(url,{ method:request.method })
        const finalresult=await result.json()
        if(result.status===400) return finalresult <-- trying to return the result here containing error message            
        ..............      
    }
    catch(err){...}
}
```

The **Login** component is a child to MainHeader.js and calls the action method in MainHeader successfully as follows:

```
fetcher.submit({logintype:data.logintype, email:txtEMail, 
    password:txtPassword},{method:'POST'})
    
return(
    <fetcher.Form action='/' >
        <p>{error}</p> <-- error message must go here
```

It's working properly and accessing the action method. However I want to return an error message from the action method back to Login.js. I assumed that it cant pass directly from the action to Login.js (because it's a child component of MainHeader.js) so I'm attempting to pass the result back to MainHeader.js and then pass it as a prop to child Login.js. I tried using the `useActionData` hook in MainHeader.js but so far it's returning undefined. How to pass the error message from the action method back to Login.js?

**UPDATE**
When I replaced `fetcher.Form` with `Form` it's working and the `useActionData` is being passed to both parent and child components. Is it that `fetch.Form` cannot return a message from the `action` method?